Why is the target  used as an input to the encoder in a semi-supervised VAE model?
As mentioned in the title, I understand the mathematical derivation of equations (6-7) in Kingma's original paper.
\begin{equation}
\log p_\theta(\mathbf{x}, y) \geq \mathbb{E}_{q_\phi(\mathbf{z} \mid \mathbf{x}, y)}\left[\log p_\theta(\mathbf{x} \mid y, \mathbf{z})+\log p_\theta(y)+\log p(\mathbf{z})-\log q_\phi(\mathbf{z} \mid \mathbf{x}, y)\right]=-\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, y)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\log p_\theta(\mathbf{x}) & \geq \mathbb{E}_{q_\phi(y, \mathbf{z} \mid \mathbf{x})}\left[\log p_\theta(\mathbf{x} \mid y, \mathbf{z})+\log p_\theta(y)+\log p(\mathbf{z})-\log q_\phi(y, \mathbf{z} \mid \mathbf{x})\right] \\
& =\sum_u q_\phi(y \mid \mathbf{x})(-\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}, y))+\mathcal{H}\left(q_\phi(y \mid \mathbf{x})\right)=-\mathcal{U}(\mathbf{x})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Here, $x$ represents the input data (which is always an image), $y$ stands for the target, and $z$ denotes the latent representation. The encoder network is denoted as $q_{\phi}$ , while the decoder network is represented by $p_{\theta}$.
However, since  is already used as the target for the classifier (seconde term of equation 9, also see it below) in the model
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{J}^\alpha=\mathcal{J}+\alpha \cdot \mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{p}_l(\mathbf{x}, y)}\left[-\log q_\phi(y \mid \mathbf{x})\right]
\end{equation}, what is the purpose of using  as an input to the encoder? Could this be redundant? It seems that removing  from the encoder's input ($\log q_\phi(\mathbf{z} \mid \mathbf{x}, y)$) also works in practice.

can you specify which equation you are referring to, and wrt which term of such equation specifically?

Thank you for your comment. I have added the specific equation and the term I was referring to.

Indeed in practice removing $y$ from the encoder might not significantly degrade performance in some cases, especially if the decoder is sufficiently capable of learning this information indirectly. Bear in mind that an expressive decoder could possibly learn to implicitly infer the target $y$ from the latent space $z$, especially when the decoder infers $y$ with a reasonable amount of accuracy during its reconstruction stage and decoder's such implicit ability to condition on $y$ may provide enough guidance to generate samples that are correctly conditioned on $y$, even if the encoder doesn't use $y$ as input explicitly.
Nonetheless, including $y$ as an input to the encoder is typically recommended for better structured learning and improved generation of $x$ given $y$. The encoder of a conditional generative model is designed to map the joint distribution of both $x$ and $y$ to a distribution over the latent variables $z$. Removing $y$ from the encoder could lead to a less accurate and efficient model, especially when the target variable $y$ provides important structure or domain-specific information that helps the encoder to generate more informative $z$.
